# Adding values to a list

Tags: python

I'm an R newbie and am trying to create a basic "database" for my comic books. 
However, I have a problem.

The idea is to place each new entry as a list.
I assumed that I could set up the lists to look like the following.

```
[Thor, 50, Marvel]
[Thor, 51, Marvel]
[Thor, 52, Marvel]
...
eventually, I 'd like to include entries for story arc, writer, artist, etc.
```

However, I'm using the following code to enter in the comics and have found that each new entry is just added to the end of the list.

```
option = 0
comicdb = []

while option != 3:
    print "--------------------------"
    print "1. Add a New Comic Book"
    print "2. Print the Database"
    print "3. Quit"
    option = int(raw_input("Pick an Option: "))
    if option == 1:
        title = raw_input("Comic Book Title: ")
        issue = int(raw_input("Issue Number: "))
        publisher = raw_input("Publisher: ")
        comicdb.append(title)
        comicdb.append(issue)
        comicdb.append(publisher)
        print comicdb
```

After running the code a couple times, the list looks like:

```
['Thor', 50, 'Marvel', 'Thor', 51, 'Marvel', 'Thor', 52, 'Marvel']
```

I'm assuming that one of the following things is wrong, but I can't figure it out:

1. append is the wrong command to use
2. i should use a dictionary or tuple instead of a list

Help!

Comment: I don't fully understand what you want to happen. What is the structure at the top of your question supposed to be? There's a list on each line, but what are the lists _in_? Are they supposed to be in a list, as in `[['a', 1], ['b', 2]]`?

Comment: That's acctually supposed to be three seperate lists.

Comment: ok, but where are they stored?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is simple. you insert 3 words to the list instead of appending a list which contains the 3 words.

It should be like this:

```
option = 0
comicdb = []

while option != 3:
    print "--------------------------"
    print "1. Add a New Comic Book"
    print "2. Print the Database"
    print "3. Quit"
    option = int(raw_input("Pick an Option: "))
    if option == 1:
        title = raw_input("Comic Book Title: ")
        issue = int(raw_input("Issue Number: "))
        publisher = raw_input("Publisher: ")
        temp_list = []
        temp_list.append(title)
        temp_list.append(issue)
        temp_list.append(publisher)
        comicdb.append(temp_list)
        print comicdb
```

Answer (score 4):

You should use a nested structure.

```
comicdb.append((title, issue, publisher))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a list of lists or a list of dictionaries.

```
record = {}
record['title'] = raw_input("Comic Book Title: ")
record['issue'] = int(raw_input("Issue Number: "))
record['publisher'] = raw_input("Publisher: ")
comicdb.append(record)
print comicdb
```

Answer (score 0):

As much as I commend your effort in writing a database from scratch, I must recommend that you have a look at [SQLAlchemy](http://sqlalchemy.org) - a Python "object relational mapper" that allows you to connect Python objects to SLQ-like databases (chiefly SQLite, the simplest, server-free one). I am amazed by the complexity that can be attained with very little code. It is clean, powerful, easy to understand, and grows rapidly.

I use it at work very successfully, and at home to keep track of all my daughters pictures (I have more megabytes (teras?) of picture of my daughters at home than I have from Cassini spacecraft at work, mind you).

So, if you are just practicing - go ahead. If you want to stand on solid ground and have a great and neat application for keeping track of your comics, then have a look at any database manager, but I recommend Python / SQLAlchemy.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just wanted to start with the basics, and eventually work my way to something like SQLAlchemy.

Comment: I still think that implementing an SQLAlchemy solution (or, really, any database manager for Python) is easier. In other words, you don't need to "make you way through" - they are very accessible.